# Delete rows present in other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables A and B containing many columns, two of which in use are SKU and Typedesc.

I created a table C by joining A and B on sku and typedesc

```
create table C as
    select A.*
    from A inner join
         B
         on A.sku=B.sku and trim(A.typedesc)=trim(B.typedesc)
```

C has approx. 130,000 records

Now I want to delete the rows in A which are present in C

```
delete from A A1
    where exists (select 1
                  from C c1
                  where A1.sku=c1.sku and trim(A1.typedesc)=trim(c1.typedesc)
                 )
```

It says 145,000 rows deleted.

Where did the extra 15,000 rows came from? Is there something wrong with my delete query? So when I join two tables, C should also have 145,000 but instead it has only 130,000!! why is this so? A or B does not contain any primary key.

Even if i delete B from A directly, the number of rows deleted remains 145,000.

```
delete from A A1
    where exists (select 1
                  from B b1
                  where A1.sku=b1.sku and trim(A1.typedesc)=trim(b1.typedesc)
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `EXISTS` looks alright, but without seeing which rows are being deleted it's hard to tell what the problem is, and I don't want to review 145,000 rows any more than you do :)

Try this alternative and see if it makes any difference:

```
DELETE FROM A
WHERE (SKU, TRIM(TypeDesc)) IN (SELECT SKU, TRIM(TypeDesc) FROM B)
```